# How can I upload files larger than 5GB to Amazon S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently using Rails 3.2 with the Carrierwave gem to upload files to Amazon S3.  Now I need to be able to handle user-submitted files larger than 5GB, while still using the Carrierwave gem.  Are there any other gems or branches of Carrierwave or Fog that can handle the 5GB+ file uploads to S3?

Edit: I'd prefer not to have to rewrite a complete Rails uploading solution, so links like this won't help: https://gist.github.com/908875 .

Comment: Check out the s3_multipart gem http://blog.bitcast.io/post/43001057745/direct-multipart-uploads-to-s3-in-rails

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured out how to do this and have it working now.  In the proper `config/environment` file, add the following to send files in 100MB chunks to Amazon S3:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_attributes = { :multipart_chunk_size => 104857600 }
end
```

Since the fog gem has multipart uploads built in (thanks to Veraticus for pointing it out), the appropriate configuration attributes just need to be passed into fog via Carrierwave.  When sending to S3 I received frequent `Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)` errors, so parts of the upload may have to be retried.

Answer (score 6):

You want to use [S3's multipart upload functionality](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html). Helpfully, Fog can indeed handle multipart S3 uploads, as you can see [in this pull request](https://github.com/fog/fog/pull/776).

Unfortunately, Carrierwave does not seem to have the functionality built in to use it correctly. So you'd need to either modify Carrierwave or drop into Fog manually to correctly upload this file.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen that Fog functionality documented anywhere.  I'll try to modify Carrierwave since all of my interactions with S3 are done through that Gem.

Answer (score -2):

You will need to break your file into small pieces prior to uploading.

**Take a look at the following:**

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/1282369

http://joemiller.me/2011/02/18/client-support-for-amazon-s3-multipart-uploads-files-5gb/

Either way, you need to split the file.

Comment: I need to do this automatically from the server with Ruby/Rails code or gems, not using external programs.

Comment: -1 So you expect lee's users to download a command line tool, split the large file up into several smaller ones, and then upload them separately? I don't think that's an answer to the question asked (or a viable solution in any way regardless).

Comment: @Ken & Lee, sorry guys i made a mistake of jumping to conclusion. Now im eager to see the answer to this question. I'm researching it and i can't seem to find any way of accomplishing this.